# Use variables in Timeout syntax on Github action pipeline

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to use some variables to set values in GitHub actions steps.

[Environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) tells us that we can set custom environment variables in your workflow file.

> By default, Linux runners use the bash shell, so you must use the syntax `$NAME`.

So I try

```
name: Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

env:
  General_Timeout_Minutes: 15

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      Setup_Timeout_Minutes: 10
      Lint_Timeout_Minutes: $General_Timeout_Minutes
      Unit_Test_Timeout_Minutes: $General_Timeout_Minutes
      E2E_Timeout_Minutes: $General_Timeout_Minutes
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup
        timeout-minutes: $Setup_Timeout_Minutes
        run: npm install

      - name: Lint JavaScript
        timeout-minutes: $Lint_Timeout_Minutes
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Run JavaScript tests
        timeout-minutes: $Unit_Test_Timeout_Minutes
        run: npm run unit-test

      - name: Run end-to-end browser tests
        timeout-minutes: $E2E_Timeout_Minutes
        run: npm run e2e-test

  deploy:
    ...
```

However, GitHub actions starts fail with

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/test.yml: Unexpected value '$Setup_Timeout_Minutes' .github/workflows/test.yml: Unexpected value '$Lint_Timeout_Minutes'

How to use variables in `timeout-minutes` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking in GitHub community and doing some tests, I get the final answer.

Here is the [discussion link](https://github.community/t/use-variables-in-timeout-syntax-on-github-action-pipeline/252149/6).

```
name: Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

env:
  General_Timeout_Minutes: 15

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      Setup_Timeout_Minutes: 10
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Set job level environment variables from global ones
      - name: "Set job env from global env"
        run: |
          echo "Lint_Timeout_Minutes=$General_Timeout_Minutes" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "Unit_Test_Timeout_Minutes=$General_Timeout_Minutes" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "E2E_Timeout_Minutes=$General_Timeout_Minutes" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Setup
        timeout-minutes: ${{ fromJSON(env.Setup_Timeout_Minutes) }}
        run: npm install

      - name: Lint JavaScript
        timeout-minutes: ${{ fromJSON(env.Lint_Timeout_Minutes) }}
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Run JavaScript tests
        timeout-minutes: ${{ fromJSON(env.Unit_Test_Timeout_Minutes) }}
        run: npm run unit-test

      - name: Run end-to-end browser tests
        timeout-minutes: ${{ fromJSON(env.E2E_Timeout_Minutes) }}
        run: npm run e2e-test

  deploy:
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome sharing your findings with us, thanks! The key here is the "fromJSON" that is responsible to convert the number as string in a real number expected by the timeout-minutes attribute.